# unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@999f0c7e xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estoy usando System.Net.Http y me genera el siguiente error al hacer una petición al servidor:
unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@999f0c7e.
El error me aparece despues de hacer varias peticiones.

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        { 
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, datos);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                System.Console.WriteLine("post estatus code ok " + jsonstring);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<respuesta>(jsonstring);
            }
            else
            {
                var jsonstring = "{ 'errorCode':'500', 'log' : '" + response.StatusCode + "'}";
                Console.WriteLine("post error estatus code" + response.StatusCode);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<respuesta>(jsonstring);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw e;
           // return default;
        }
```

[image: les dejo lo que me muestra en la consola]

Comment: Deberias poner bien el error que te lanza. completo, ese error lo vez en el catch o donde?

Comment: si, me lo muestra en el catch

Comment: claro, pero dentro de ex tenes la propiedad message. fijate en ex.message que te dice

Comment: e.Message lo pongo en un console.WriteLine() y me responde con esto "unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@1b062200"

Comment: que version de Android estas corriendo?

Comment: la versión de Android es 9

Answer (score 0):

**Ya solucione mi error**

```
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        request.Content =datos;
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";
        request.Headers.Add("Connection", "close");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

`

Comment: Indica en tu respuesta qué has corregido en el código para que funcione: lee [answer].